# Why does 'Giclee Print' not have 'Digital' included?

Tags: print-design, print-production, digital-printing

I am in the process of putting together various 'Digital Prints' and 'Giclee Prints', which will be available for sale in the future.

Done correctly, a Giclee Print should be of better quality than its Digital counterpart.  As such, Giclee Prints typically being more expensive.

With this in mind, I was thinking of branding my future Digital Prints as 'Standard Prints' with the Giclee Prints being referred to as the 'Premium Prints'.  For me, this makes logical sense.

The problem I am having, however, is that most Artists and Customers refer to the standard prints as 'Digital Prints' with the Giclee Prints as, well, 'Giclee Prints'.  In other words, excluding 'Digital' from the 'Giclee Prints', despite a Giclee also being a Digital Print.

What is bothering me here, is that both print variants are Digital, yet only the cheaper of the two is actually referred to as a 'Digital Print'.

Is there a right and wrong way to refer to these variants?  Maybe they are referred to as 'Digital Prints' and 'Digital Giclee Prints', with 'Digital' simply being dropped from the latter or maybe Giclee was introduced at a time when Digital Printing was not around, where it has simply embraced Digital Printing, whilst maintaining its original name?

Answer (score 1):

Any high quality digital print can be referred to as "Giclee" -- it's merely a *marketing term* used to ramp up pricing.

Technically *both* a "digital print" and a "Giclee print" can come off the *exact same* printer.  How you choose to differentiate between them is really about *sales and marketing* not technology.

Same reason name brand groceries cost more than their generic brand competitors -- same *exact* ingredients... but the name raises pricing.

The differentiator *is* the word "Giclee" and an expectation that the consumer won't be wise enough to understand it's the same thing.  Using "Giclee Print", "Digital Giclee Print" or "Giclee Digital Print" doesn't really matter - it's all merely sales "spin". You could call the high-end prints "Premiere Executive Giclee Prints" or call them "Craig's Super Cool Bitchin' Quality Prints" doesn't change the production method.